# Write a c# program to find the smallest of three numbers using nested if statement?

Tags: c#

A nested if is an if statement that is the target of another if statement. Nested if statements means an if statement inside another if statement. Yes, C++ allows us to nest if statements within if statements. i.e, we can place an if statement inside another if statement.

Comment: Please note that you have made a statement, not a question. Nobody can answer anything to it. It also looks like a homework assignment or similar, which requires you to at least attempt it. Do check out the [tour] and the [help] on how and what to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
int c=3;
if (b>a) {
    if (b>c) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
} else {
    if (a>c) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
```